# converting swift 3 project to use CoreData

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm relatively new to Swift and Cocoa worlds and would love to get peoples opinions on whats the best way to design the data model for the following:

I currently have a prototype project for macOS that has the following (simplified) data model:

```
class Loan: NSObject, XMLParseDelegate {
   var id: Int
   var address: Address
   // ... other properties and methods
   func parseZillow() {
   // bunch of code, etc
   }
}
```

where `Address` is another class structure that has its own properties and methods. I then have an array of [`Loan`] bound to `NSArrayController` and `NSTableView` using Cocoa Bindings (and everything works nicely, except now i want to introduce persistent storage into the picture)

Now the (two-part) question:

1) if i was to represent this structure with CoreData model - how do I represent the nested class structure of `loan.address` path?   do i just have 2 Entities in CoreData (Loans and Addresses) and have a one-to-one relationship between the two? is this the best practice?

2) my understanding of CoreData is that instead of using the Array of `[Loan]` as my data model, CoreData will be the new data model (and will create a managed object representing my data schema similar to what i have currently as my `class Loan` object.  Where would I define the methods that I currently have for my `Loan` and `Address` classes? Do I need to create a wrapper class on top of the MO?   I've looked at a bunch of tutorials but this part is still not clear to me

Comment: Warning: Core Data is not a beginner technology.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can have two entities, Loan and Address. If each loan has one address and each address has one loan the relationship is one-to-one. If an address can have multiple loans, the relationship is many-to-one.
2. From [Creating and Saving Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1)

> Creating NSManagedObject Subclasses
>
> By default, Core Data will return NSManagedObject instances to your application. However, it is useful to define subclasses of NSManagedObject for each of the entities in your model. Speciflcally, when you create subclasses of NSManagedObject, you can define the properties that the entity can use for code completion and you can add convenience methods to those subclasses.
>
> To create a subclass of NSManagedObject, in Xcode’s Core Data model editor, select the entity, and in the Entity pane of the Data Model inspector, enter the name in the Class field. Then create the subclass (AAAEmployeeMO) in Xcode.

'Create NSManagedObject Subclass…' is in the Editor menu. You can create all subclasses at once. You can add your methods to the NSManagedObject Subclasses.